# Как правильно разобрать JSON объект

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

Возможно такой вопрос задавали, но я не нашел((. 
Помогите составить модель для данного вида json, ответ получаю в виде объекта, был бы массив без проблем разобрал бы.

```
{
    "0": {
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Антон",
        "birthday": {
            "year": "1978",
            "month": "03",
            "day": "05",
            "zodiac": {
                "name": "Рыбы"
            }
        }
    },
    "1": {
        "id": "2",       
        "name": "Наталия",
        "birthday": {
            "year": "1973",
            "month": "05",
            "day": "23",
            "zodiac": {
                "name": "Близнецы"
            }
        }
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "3",       
        "name": "Света",
        "birthday": {
            "year": "1991",
            "month": "04",
            "day": "14",
            "zodiac": {
                "name": "Овен"
            }
        }
    },
    "execution_time": 0.1185
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Jackson или Gson?

Comment: Прошу прощения не уточнил, Gson

Comment: "0", "1", "2" - это ключи? Или они меняться могут?

Comment: Это они увеличиваются на +1 по мере надобности, могут достигать и 100 и 200, по этому я и не могу разобраться

Answer (score 1):

Я полагаю у вас уже есть некий класс `Person`.

Написать свой десериалайзер

```
class PersonsDeserializer : JsonDeserializer<List<Person>> {
    override fun deserialize(json: JsonElement, typeOfT: Type, context: JsonDeserializationContext): List<Person> {
        val persons = ArrayList<Person>()
        for (entry in json.asJsonObject.entrySet()) {
            try { persons.add(context.deserialize<Person>(entry.value, Person::class.java))
            } catch (ignore: JsonParseException) { }
        }
        return persons
    }
}
```

Применить

```
@JsonAdapter(PersonsDeserializer.class) 
data class PersonsResponse : ArrayList<Person>
```

Должно сработать)

код на `Kotlin`

Comment: Я пишу не на Kotlin`е и нижнего класса тоже нет, я выложил скриншот для более лучшей наглядности

Comment: @dev.android Понять что тут происходит несложно. Нижний класс нужно завести и наследовать от ArrayList.

Comment: Мне самое главное понять как создать правильно модель, если не сложно приведите пожалуйста, буду очень признателен

Comment: Нижний класс и есть модель ```@JsonAdapter(PersonsDeserializer.class) 
class PersonsResponse extends ArrayList<Person>```

Comment: Не помогло(( Возможно я сделал что-то не так